# ggplot2 not rendering correctly using Plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have created a point plot using ggplot2 that works relatively well.  I would love to run in using Plotly, however when I do - it ends up upsetting the y axis and making the legend very wonky.  I will post some before and after below but I am very new to both and looking for the right direction.  The ggplot2 is okay but the added interactivity of plotly would be a huge win for what we are doing.  Also a weird note - the top graph returned seems to cut off the plot (the highest value - not sure why). Thanks.

Code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(sqldf)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rio) #lets you use "import" for any file - without using extension name
options(scipen =999) #disable scientific notation



#prepare data:

setwd("C:/Users/hayescod/Desktop/BuysToForecastTracking")
Buys_To_Forecast <- import("BuysToForecastTrack")

colnames(Buys_To_Forecast) <- c("Date", "BusinessSegment", "Material", "StockNumber", "POCreatedBy", "PlantCode", "StockCategory", "Description", "Excess", "QuantityBought", "WareHouseSalesOrders", "GrandTotal", "Comments" )
Buys_To_Forecast$PlantCode <-factor(Buys_To_Forecast$PlantCode) #update PlantCode to factor


#use SQL to filter and order the data set: 

btf <- sqldf("SELECT Date, 
                     SUM(QuantityBought) AS 'QuantityBought', 
                     Comments
              FROM   Buys_To_Forecast 
              GROUP BY Date, Comments
              ORDER BY Date")
#use ggplot:

btfnew <- ggplot(data=btf, aes(x=Date, y=QuantityBought, color=Comments, size=QuantityBought)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(Comments~., scales="free")+ 
  ggtitle("Buys To Forecast Review")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="DarkBlue", size = 18), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="Red", size = 14))

btfnew #display the plot in ggplot

ggplotly(btfnew) #display the plot in Plotly
```

Comment: I just realized I don't know how to put images into Stack Overflow !

Comment: Try providing a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and you won't need the images as people can plot themselves